# Confluence to show equivalent terms have one common reduct

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, term-rewriting, types-and-programming-languages

In lemma 30.3.9, Pierce states a confluence property for $F_{\omega}$:

> $S \to_* T \land S \to_* U \implies \exists V. T \to_* V \land U \to_* V$

He then states the following proposition:

> $S \leftrightarrow_* T \implies \exists U. S \to_* U \land T \to_* U$

However, he doesn´t use the above property to prove it. I remember this was the case for other books on term rewriting systems that I read. However, to me it looks very simple to prove using the confluence lemma.

From $S \leftrightarrow_* T$ one has $S \to_* T$ and $S \to_* T \to_* S$ thus by confluence $\exists U. S \to_* U \land T \to_* U$.

Why is this approach not correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$S \leftrightarrow^* T$ does not mean that $S \rightarrow^* T$ and $T \rightarrow^* S$! It means that there is a chain of reductions $S = S_0 \rightleftharpoons_1 S_1 \rightleftharpoons_2 S_2 \rightleftharpoons_3 \cdots \rightleftharpoons_n S_n = T$ where each of the $\rightleftharpoons_i$ might be either $\rightarrow$ or $\leftarrow$. The directions can alternate any number of times.

The confluence property does imply generically that if $S \leftrightarrow^* T$ then there exists $W$ such that $S \rightarrow^* W \leftarrow^* T$, but it takes a bit more work to show it. You can combine reductions in $S \leftrightarrow^* T$ to group consecutive reductions in the same direction together: $S = T_0 \leftarrow^* U_1 \rightarrow^* T_1 \leftarrow^* U_2 \rightarrow^* T_2 \leftarrow^* \cdots \leftarrow^* U_n \rightarrow^* T_n = T$. By confluence on $T_{n-1} \leftarrow^* U_n \rightarrow^* T_n$, there exists $V_n$ such that $T_{n-1} \rightarrow^* V_n \leftarrow^* T_n$. So we have $T_{n-2} \leftarrow^* U_{n-1} \rightarrow^* T_{n-1} \rightarrow^* V_n \leftarrow^* T_n$.

$$
\begin{matrix}
    &            & U_1 &            &     &        &         &            & U_{n-1} &            &     &            & U_n &            &     \\
    & _*\swarrow &     & \searrow^* &     & \cdots &         & _*\swarrow &     & \searrow^* &     & _*\swarrow &     & \searrow^* &     \\
T_0 &            &     &            & T_1 &        & T_{n-2} &            &     &            & T_{n-1} &            &     &            & T_n \\
    &            &     &            &     &        &         &            &     & 
           &     & \color{green}{\searrow^*} &     & \color{green}{_*\swarrow} &     \\
    &            &     &            &     &        &         &            &         &            &     &            & \color{green}{V_n} &            &     \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Now apply the confluence property again to $T_{n-2} \leftarrow^* U_{n-1} \rightarrow^* V_n$, getting $V_{n-1}$ such that $T_{n-2} \rightarrow^* V_{n-1} \leftarrow^* V_n \leftarrow^* T_n$. Repeat until you get $W = V_1$ such that $T_0 \rightarrow^* V_1 \leftarrow^* T_n$. Formally, this is a proof by induction on the number of alternations of directions in the chain $S \leftrightarrow^* T$. Confluence lets you remove one alternation at a time. In more colorful language, confluence lets you “pop a crease”; each time you pop a crease, you join two depressions together, and if you keep doing that, you eventually get a single depression.

Comment: the first line clarified years of misunderstanding, thanks

Comment: Good job with those finicky diagrams!